# RxSwift: button click action from awakeFromNib to UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I am `Rx-Swift` beginner. I am trying to get `UIButton` action which is present inside `UITableViewCell`.

**Attempt:**

1. I have tried with `UITableViewCell's` instance that I can get from `UIViewController`. Thats working fine.

**Need:**

- How can I transfer that clicked tag value from `awakeFromNib()` to `UIViewController` ?

**Code:**

```
// UITableViewCell

class TripInfoCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var btnMore: UIButton!
    var cellbag = DisposeBag()

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        cellbag = DisposeBag()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()


        btnMore.rx.tap.asObservable()
           .subscribe { _ in

            print("Tapping_   ", self.tag)

        }.disposed(by: cellbag)

    }

}


// UIViewController
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Observable.of(visitsModel).bind(to: tblView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "cell", cellType: TripInfoCell.self)) { (row, element, cell) in

       cell.tag = row

    }
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

**Attempt:**

Here, `UIButton` action I have used inside `UIViewController`. So I can transfer data.

```
Observable.of(visitsModel).bind(to: tblView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "cell", cellType: TripInfoCell.self)) { (row, element, cell) in

      cell.tag = row

      cell.btnMore.rx.tap.asObservable()
           .subscribe { _ in

           print("Inside_Tapping_   ", cell.tag)

      }.disposed(by: cell.cellbag)


}
```

Comment: It looks like your second attempt does what you wanted to do. If not, then exactly what are you asking for?

Comment: I need button action from `awakeFromNib()` to `UIViewController`

Comment: How is the one in `awakeFromNib()` different than the one you have in your `items` closure?

Comment: I haven't said that both are different. I just want to know data transfer from `awakeFromNib()` to `UIViewController`.